# How can I /give a named painting in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm attempting to give a player a painting named 'hel' using the following command:

```
give @p painting 1 0 {display:{name:"hel"}}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Line 1, Column 2
> Missing '}' or object member name

I've tried everything I can think of to fix it. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Command Block Window]

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quote marks (") around the attribute names in the JSON.

That is:

```
/give @p painting 1 0 {"display":{"name":"hel"}}
```

instead of:

```
/give @p painting 1 0 {display:{name:"hel"}}
```

That being said, "display" is not a supported component, so what you're trying to do wouldn't work in the first place.

According to https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/give

> *components: json* (optional)‌<sup>[Bedrock Edition only]</sup>
>
> Like DataTags but only supports `CanPlaceOn` and `CanDestroy` functions (for example,
>      `/give @p iron_shovel 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["grass"]}}`)

Comment: Is there a way that I can give a rename item?

Comment: @Piew_Piew, unfortunately, it seems that is (currently) not possible in Bedrock edition. According to a reddit thread, one workaround is to put a named item in a chest, and then clone the item to where the player is: https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/cd19m4/trying_to_give_a_named_item_on_minecraft_bedrock/